# API GET method : Unsupported Protocol

Tags: rest, ssl

I have an rest api that was working well few days ago. However , it stopped working. When I checked the access_token , it is not expired. Has anybody encountered such problem?

But the get method gives following error when I checked in rest client app :

```
Trying 99.86.230.110...
Name '0.0.0.0' family 2 resolved to '0.0.0.0' family 2
Local port: 0
Connected to api-v2.myapi.it.com (99.86.230.110) port 443 (#0)
ALPN, offering http/1.1
Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
successfully set certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Unknown (21):
TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
Closing connection 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a TLS problem and has nothing to do with access tokens. The problem is on the server side, i.e. the server aborts the TLS handshake with a TLS alert "handshake failure". Since this is happening immediately after the client initiated the TLS handshake and before any server certificate is send it might be a misconfigured server which cannot find its certificate. Check with the API provider of why there systems suddenly have problems.